# how to rotate the screen when clicking on a fulscreen button?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to do as on YouTube, which when clicking on the maximize icon the screen automatically rotates. In my code, it maximizes, but remains vertical.
ps: I want to do this on cell phone.

```
<iframe id="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Lg6YYMZzxVk?enablejsapi=1&html5=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&rel=0" 
         frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <button onclick= "openFullscreen();" id="overlayDesktop" style="z-index: 0; text-align: center;"><img class="icons" src="../icons/full-screen.svg" title="FULLSCREEN"></button>

    <script>
      var elem = document.getElementById("video");
                    function openFullscreen() {
                        if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
                            elem.requestFullscreen();
                        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
                            elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
                        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
                            elem.msRequestFullscreen();
                        }
                    }
    </script>
```

Comment: The rotation happens in mobile not on desktop. please add it in the question to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the screen with:

- CSS
- HTML5
- Javascript
- Device Orientation API
- Screen Orientation API
- etc.

I think the best choose is screen orientation API for you.

---

Source: https://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/master-screen-orientation-html5-101517371